# Динамическое изменение selected через jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Есть такой иерархический DropDown.

```
<select id="estimateA">
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">\u00a0_Test1</option>
    <option value="3">\u00a0\u00a0_Test1_1</option>
    <option value="4">\u00a0_Test2</option>
    <option value="5">\u00a0\u00a0_Test2_1</option>
    <option value="6">\u00a0\u00a0_Test2_2</option>
</select>
```

Подскажите, как сделать так чтобы на выбранном элементе не было лишних пробелов?

Сейчас делаю следующим образом:

```
 $('#estimateA').change(function () { 
    //возвращаю элементам неразрывные пробелы
    $("#estimateA option").each( 
    function paintPackageTable() {
        var $cell = $(this);
        $cell.text($cell.text().replace(/  /g, '\u00a0\u00a0'));
        }
    );
    //возвращаю элементам неразрывные пробелы
    var $cell1 = $("#estimateA option:selected");
    $cell.text($cell1.text().replace(/\u00a0\u00a0/g, '  '));
});
```

т.е. чтобы в выпадающем списке была видна иерархия, а при выборе и отображении в "свернутом" состоянии - не было лишних пробелов?

**Обновление**

При "разворачивании" dropdown-а там где неразрывные пробелы заменяются обычными текст "прижимается" к левому краю. А хочется чтобы он прижимался только когда список свернут и "иерархичность" в нем не нарушалась

Comment: А что не работает в вашем решении?

Answer (score 1):

Как временное решение сделал так, осталась проблема - при "разворачивании" выбранный элемент нарушает иерархию.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#estimateA").on("change", function(event) {
    $("#estimateA option").each(function() {
      var $cell = $(this);
      $cell.text($cell.text().replace(/\u200B/g, "\u2007"))
    });
    var $cell = $("#estimateA option:selected");
    $cell.text($cell.text().replace(/\u2007/g, "\u200b"))
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="estimateA">
  <option value="1">Test</option>
  <option value="2">&#8199;_Test1</option>
  <option value="3">&#8199;&#8199;_Test1_1</option>
  <option value="4">&#8199;_Test2</option>
  <option value="5">&#8199;&#8199;_Test2_1</option>
  <option value="6">&#8199;&#8199;_Test2_2</option>
</select>
```